# Guzzle Url issue in PHP

Tags: php, guzzle

I am using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) for API requests.

My calling API url looks like: `base_url/order/11111?param=1&param2=2`

This is my code:

```
try{
    $data = http_build_query([
         'amount' => 500,
         'products' => $order['products'], 
         'currency' => 'EURO'
    ], '', '&amp;');

    $client->request('GET', $base_url"/order/{$order['id']}?".$data, [
          'connect_timeout' => 3, 
          'timeout' => 3 
    ]);
}catch(Exception $er){
    var_dump($er);
}
```

I am always ending up in the exception  and getting `my url .... resulted in a 404 Not Found`. Because an extra `\` is added after `$order['id']`
so my url looks like `base_url/order/11111\?param=1&param2=2` , which will end up in the browser like `base_url/order/11111/?param=1&param2=2`

I also tried to add the `query` param to the request. The result is the same. Is there a way to remove that extra `\` ? or can you tell me what is the cause of  adding it ?

Comment: Does `$order['id']` actually end in \ or is that coming from somewhere else?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `&amp;` as the separator? That wouldn't explain an extra slash being added, but it doesn't look right.

Comment: @apokryfos it's just an integer

Comment: @iainn , I don't think that is the issue, but what is your idea ? :) could you share it ? thank you

Comment: Check whether there's a redirect on the remote server which adds trailing slashes. Set the option `"allow_redirects" => false` to see if you get a redirect response and if so then contact the API provider and let them know you're having issues. It may be just a bug on the 3rd party API